# CSS for inverted curved tabs

Tags: css, tabs, css-shapes

I've gotten stuck on how to code the css for these inverted curvy tabs that were supplied by a design agency.

[image]

see here: http://max-guedy.com/images/tab.png

Comment: hint: you'll probably end up using a sprite image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a demo how I would do it:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/otoqij/edit#javascript,html,live)*

- We set the brown color to the whole ul element
- a 25x52 sprite image .png of the curve : (will change bg-position on hover)
  http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/258/bg2d.png that we will set to the `li` element but with no bg color.
- The most importsnt here is to setup a higher z-index to the `li` elements, decreasing it on `hover`
- Take care to set to the `a` elements left padding and respective -left margin to allow the anchor to 'hide' below the previous element image.

Done that you can have wide and wider links and your template will do the work!

and this CSS:

```
  ul#nav{
    height:26px;
    background:#A15049;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
  }
  ul#nav li{
    position:relative;
    background:transparent url(http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/258/bg2d.png) no-repeat right top;
    height:26px;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    padding:0 25px 0 5px;
    z-index:1;
  }
  ul#nav li a{
    padding-left:24px;
    margin-left:-24px;
    height:26px;
    display:block;
    color:#fff;
  }
  
  ul#nav li:hover{
    z-index:0;
    background: url(http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/258/bg2d.png) no-repeat right -26px;
  }
  ul#nav li:hover a{
    background:#CE392C;
  }
```

Comment: you might want to add a roll-over effect or an 'active tab' highlight to that demo. The OP's sample image didn't show them, but I'd put money on them being needed.

Comment: OP's image has no `background-color` on the "tab bar". I recommend adjusting the sprite so that the `background-color` of the last item doesn't show through.

Comment: @Spudley Added example with hover.

Comment: @Roko - awesome. looks good.  :)  (oh, and +1 by the way... I meant to give it to you earlier anyway, but I forgot. you can have it now though)

Comment: @Roko thank you so much for your time and efforts! apart from a +1, how else can i thank you?

Answer (score 2):

It is just about possible to achieve this kind of thing with CSS.

Very difficult, but possible.

By default, `border-radius` of course only gives you regular rounded corners.

You can stretch them to some interesting shapes by adjusting the radius values. This will get you some of the way to your goal.

But the real trick here, to get the round-out parts of the tabs, is to use the CSS `:before` and `:after` pseudo-selectors to create additional styling elements, to which you need to add further `border-radius`.

The technique is described here: http://css-tricks.com/better-tabs-with-round-out-borders/ ... albeit for a fairly simple vertical-shaped tab. But it does a good job of explaining how to achieve the turn-out effect, which will be critical to you if you want to do this in CSS.

Bear in mind also that none of this will work in old versions of IE. IE8 does support `:before` and `:after`, but not `border-radius`. And while hacks like CSS3Pie exist to fix that, I wouldn't recommend using them for this kind of thing. It is likely to break.

If all the above sounds quite tricky and not really worth it, I would tend to agree. I think you'll find that a few simple images will work much better for your tabs in this instance. You could also try SVG to draw them if you want to be clever, but this will also have issues with old versions of IE.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You're easier off using images.

But if you insist on using CSS, I'd say that you need to use a lot of`border-radius`

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting challenge.

My first idea was to apply a skew transform to the tabs, a border radius to the top right corner and take care of the rounded lower part using a pseudo-element.

Unfortunately, this looks ugly http://dabblet.com/gist/2759785

Still, it bugs me that there must be a better way to do it with pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's possible, but the amount of time that it would take would not be worth it, especially because it won't work in IE < 9...

There is a good tutorial that I have used in the past at [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/better-tabs-with-round-out-borders/)

However, as others have pointed out, I would recommend using images.

Comment: IE8 supports pseudo-elements which means that the method you linked can work in IE8.

Comment: Also, let's be real. The amount of time it would take to use a sprite image would probably equal, if not surpass, using `border-radius` and pseudo-elements.

Comment: @gmeben - IE8 does indeed support `:before` and `:after`, but it does not support `border-radius`, so the technique won't work in IE8.

Comment: @Spudley >"Since IE8 and IE9 do support :before and :after but not border-radius you'll have to create a separate stylesheet for them if you want to give their users a nice visual experience." Using this technique with a sprite image should work just fine.

Comment: @gmeben - Yes, images will work fine, of course, but the way I read the answer, his "won't work in IE<9" comment was referring to the CSS technique discussed in the link.

Comment: @gmeben: IE9 supports border-radius

Comment: @Ana - gmeben is quoting from the linked article. The article is incorrect on this point (I think it may have been written while IE9 was still in beta; the early versions may not have supported border radius)

Comment: @gmeden - Really? If you think that using `border-radius` would be equal time to image sprites, you must be slow at doing image sprites.  As you can see above, someone already made a demo of an image sprite, but the same can't be said about using css techniques as it was take a lot more time.

Comment: @LeeR I never said sprites take a long time to do, I said it equals or takes less time. If you think that using `border-radius` takes a long time to do, then you must be slow at developing.

Comment: @gmeden - `border-radius` doesn't take a long time to do. What will take a long time to do, would be to get what he wants done. To accomplish what he wants done with css would indeed take a much longer time then using simple sprites. If you want to prove me wrong, please do. Do both from scratch in jsFiddle, and tell me your link and your time. I would be interested to see.

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't take THAT much CSS to achieve this anymore. Granted you'll have to toy with the radius' to get the desired slant.

**HTML**

```
<div role="tablist">
    <a href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="active-tab1" aria-selected="true">active tab</a>
    <a href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="active-tab2">inactive tab</a>
    <a href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="active-tab3">inactive tab</a>
</div>

<div class="pane">
    <section id="active-tab1" role="tabpanel">
        <p>Show whatever</p>
        <p>You Want</p>
        <ul>
            <li>inside</li>
            <li>This</li>
            <li>Section</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section id="active-tab2" role="tabpanel">
    </section>
    <section id="active-tab3" role="tabpanel">
    </section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
[role=tablist]{padding:15px 15px 0;margin-left:88px;}

[role=tab]{
    color:#222;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:44px;
    position:relative;
    min-width:150px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:15px 15px 0 0}
[role=tab]:hover{background-color:#ecf0f1;color:#222;}
[role=tab][aria-selected=true]{
    background-color:#3498db;
    color:white; }
[role=tab]:before,
[role=tab]:after{
    content:'';
    border-bottom:10px solid #3498db;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-10px;
    width:44px;
    height:22px;
    z-index:1; }
[role=tab][aria-selected=true]:before{
    left:-44px;
    border-right:10px solid #3498db;
    border-bottom-right-radius:25px;
}
[role=tab][aria-selected=true]:after {
    right:-44px;
    border-left:10px solid #3498db;
    border-bottom-left-radius:25px;
}

.pane{
    background-color:#3498db;
    padding:25px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    color:white;
    border-radius:15px;
}
```

And odds are you can slim even that down, made it in about 10 minutes.

http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/819yz9Ly/