# CSS div title with H3 like the example attached

Tags: css

please check this example which I am trying to achieve..
[image: http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg651/scaled.php?server=651&filename=cssre.gif&res=landing]

the title is automatically stretched when there is more text.. it can be seen here
http://demo.gavick.com/joomla15/mar2009/

cheers

Comment: "the title is automatically stretched".  Isn't that the desired result? What's the question?

Comment: Thanks.. how to embed H3 code within DIV and write the correct css code that will make it look like the above example.. cheers

Comment: Oh, so that site isn't yours, and you just want to copy it?  Why not look at their CSS and see how they do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want the background part with the rounded angled ends done entirely in CSS? It isn't easy, but it can be done, in the same manner as [these tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684524/how-do-i-make-a-slated-rounded-border-on-a-html-element/10684564#10684564) (check the dabblet). The "strechable" aspect is the easy part, as it's handled by just one line of code (`display:inline-block;`) on the containing `div`.

Done with just CSS, absolutely no images http://dabblet.com/gist/3166401

HTML structure is simple:

```
<div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="heading-container">
        <h3>FEATURED STORY - exapandable: add or remove text here</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.box-wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    min-height: 150px;
    margin: 175px auto;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
.heading-container {
    left: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(#3c72a4, #345a7c);
}
.heading-container h3 {
    margin: 0;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font: 700 10px/20px /* 20px, just like the height */ Helvetica;
    color: #fff;
}
.heading-container:before, 
.heading-container:after {
    top: 0;
    width: 20px; /* just like the height of .heading-container */
    height: 20px; /* just like the height of .heading-container */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    background: linear-gradient(#3c72a4, #345a7c);
    content: '';
}
.heading-container:before {
    left: -10px; /* 10px = half the height of .heading-container */
    border-radius: 0 0 0 25%; /* 25% = a quarter (of 20px) */
    transform: skewX(25deg);
}
.heading-container:after {
    right: -10px; /* 10px = half the height of .heading-container */
    border-radius: 0 0 25% 0; /* 25% = a quarter (of 20px) */
    transform: skewX(-25deg);
}
.heading-container h3:before, 
.heading-container h3:after {
    top: 0;
    width: 5px; /* same as the border-radius for .heading-container:before and :after */
    height: 5px; /* same as the border-radius for .heading-container:before and :after */
    position: absolute;
    background: #f00;
    content: '';
}
.heading-container h3:before {
    left: -18px;
    transform: skewX(25deg);
    background: radial-gradient(left bottom, 
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 70.71%, #3b7a9c 70.71%);
    /* 70.71% = (2 * 100%)/sqrt(2) */
}
.heading-container h3:after {
    right: -18px;
    transform: skewX(-25deg);
    background: radial-gradient(right bottom, 
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 70.71%, #3b7a9c 70.71%);
}
```

Comment: both answers are great, I dont know which to see right, I see you spent a lot of time on it..

THANK YOU BOTH...

Comment: Hi again Ana.. thats wonderful and it has given me completely new direction for exploring the limits of css, thanks.. however I have tried embedding in my code, it works fine if I put in only in <body>

but if I put it my divs, it doesnt work, can you please quickly look at my code here : http://jsfiddle.net/sTXJW/2/

thanks

Comment: Check it now http://jsfiddle.net/sTXJW/5/ First of all, don't put html tags in the CSS panel in jsFiddle, just the CSS. And I had used `z-index: -1`on the pseudo-elements for the containing div so they were hidden behind the green background. I removed it and now they are in front.

Comment: Ana - you are a life saver :) let me be your student from now on :) I will catch you on twitter.. thanks a lot..

Comment: What kind of IE support do you need for it? I didn't care about it initially and now I revised it a bit http://dabblet.com/gist/3166401/432884f6c02d49f78f37c2710c8285766b9c0f34 for a decent looking fallback. It can be improved. Especially the gradient is easy to achieve - takes just an IE filter. Even more, if you have a solid colour background (no RGBa, no images) for the box, then IE9 can be convinced to show it just like Firefox or Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Let's pretend and assume that the background-image for the `<h3>` element is 20px wide.

Apply `display:inline-block` to `<h3>` as well as the `<span>` within it. Then, taking the width of the background-image of the `<h3>` into consideration, we will set a value for margin-left to the `<span>` to have it move over (which will then, in fact, reveal the background-image of the h3).

```
h3, h3 span {
 display: inline-block;
}

h3 span {
 margin-left: 20px; /* This is assuming that the background-image of h3 is 20px wide; change accordingly */
}
```

When all is said and done, add a linebreak (`<br>`) after the `<h3>` element, and all should be fine! Or, you can wrap the other text in a different block element/div for a linebreak.

Comment: This is correct. H3 is a block level element and therefore its background takes up the entire available width. To make the background elastic to fit the text contained in the H3, change the display to inline-block as Vinny suggests. Here is a link to a more comprehensive explanation: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/display

Comment: thanks, below is my css:

<code>
<style>
h3{
 color: #fff;
 background: url(./mtable_h3_light_left.png) no-repeat 0 0;
 display: inline-block;

}

h3 span{
 background: url(./mtable_h3_light_right.png) no-repeat right 0; 

}

.tableHead{
 color: #999;
 background: url(./module_light_bg.png) repeat-x 0 bottom;
 border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
</style>
</code>

and here is html

<code>
      <div class="tableHead">
        <h3><span>Featured Story</span></h3>
        test
      </div>
</code>

Comment: now the problem is, its not aligned, he left image is behind the right image so its hidden, secondly the test is also in front is h3, how to put the TEST word under H3 and also show the left image starting within H3.. cheers

Comment: @Max What are the dimensions of the left image?

Answer (score 0):

Put a width of 87% to the h3 child span:

```
div.moduletable h3 span { 
  width:87%;
}
```